# How can I download an iOS app I released to European app stores when I'm in the U.S for testing purposes?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I released an iOS app to several European countries in the App Store. I'm a U.S. based developer but, I would like to test out downloading the production build in order to try out something that is only supposed to be available in a production release.

How can I download the app from the store when I did not allow it to be available in the U.S.? Is there a way for confirmed Apple iOS developers to do such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

as a developer - not AFAIK.
you can however open a local app store account at Europe using a different email, and switch your device's Appstore to the local Appstore there. 
you'll be able to download your app then if its free. (if not you'll need to use a local payment method).

Comment: Will give that a try, thanks. If no one comes through with a more direct solution I will go ahead and mark yours as the answer.

Comment: My app is free yet they are still forcing me to enter in a payment method